# Why does "one-night stand" mean sex?

Tags: meaning

What does the word *stand* mean in this phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From NOAD:

> **one-night stand**
>   *noun*
>   1 informal (also one-nighter) *a sexual relationship lasting only one night*.
>   • a person with whom one has such a relationship.
>   2 a single performance of a play or show in a particular place.

The etymology is from the "play or show" meaning and the word probably comes from "stand" used in the military sense, as a confrontation:

> • an act of holding one's ground against or halting to resist an opposing force : *Custer's legendary last stand*

Comment: so, stand=fighting and sex is like a fighting? Yes. I see.

Comment: @snooze: It is if you do it right. :)

Comment: I thought it was from  travelling shows/circuses and towns that were only worth a single night. so after a one night stand they were gone in the morning

Comment: Steven King's _The Stand_

Comment: @Martin Beckett: See the part where I say 'The etymology is from the "play or show" meaning'.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: So, the 'stand' here is used as a noun and means the stage of show/circuses ?

Comment: @snooze - 'performance' might be closer

Answer (score 22):

The OED says s.v. "stand":

> e. Theatr. Each of the halts made on a tour to give performances; the place at which a halt is made; the performance itself; transf., esp. in one-night stand n. at one-night adj. Special uses.

So the "stand" is the stopping place on a theatrical tour. The one-night stand is a place where the show is performed for only one night. Nothing to do with fighting.

Comment: I have to say, your answer is more clear. But I have marked my answer.

Comment: @lovespring: You can un-accept the original answer and mark this one, if you so wish.

Comment: "One-night stand" was at one time a common phrase among performers for such a one-day performance stop. The term was appropriated to a sexual context, comparing it to such a performance. (I don't know if performers still use the term or if it is now so totally associated with sex that it would be misunderstood.)

Answer (score 0):

The participants in a 'one-night stand' usually not know each other and have no intention or expectation of a relationship to come out of it.

'Stand' here is also used to describe the relationship, if any, as 'The relationship only stands for one night'.

Comment: I was always under the impression that the "stand" is equivalent to being "stood up" for any further activity.

Comment: It is possible that the "stand" is understood to have one of those meanings, but I have never understood it so, and it pretty clearly wasn't in the origin.